# Spark Using Java - No live SolrServers available to handle this request

Tags: java, apache-spark, solr

full code

```
public class SolrToMongodb {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SolrToMongodb.class);
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SolrServerException {
    SolrToMongodb main = new SolrToMongodb();
    main.run();
}

public void run() throws IOException, SolrServerException {
    SparkConfig config = new SparkConfig();
    JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(config.sparkConf("admiralty-stream"));

    SolrClient client = new HttpSolrClient(Constant.SOLR_STREAMING);
    SolrQuery q = new SolrQuery();
    q.set("q","*:*");
    q.set("indent","on");
    q.set("wt", "json");

    client.query(q);


    try {
        CloudSolrClient cloudSolrClient = new CloudSolrClient(Constant.ZOOKEEPER_SOLR);

        SolrJavaRDD solrRDD = SolrJavaRDD.get(cloudSolrClient.getZkHost(), "admiraltyStream", jsc.sc());

        JavaRDD<SolrDocument> resultsRDD = solrRDD.queryShards(q);

        JavaRDD<Object> objectJavaRDD = resultsRDD.map(new Function<SolrDocument, Object>() {

            @Override
            public Object call(SolrDocument v1) throws Exception {
                System.out.println(v1.getFieldValueMap());
                return v1.getFieldValueMap();
            }
        });

    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception here : "+e.getMessage());
    }
}}
```

ERROR LOG :

> 2017-08-02 10:02:58,709 [main] ERROR CloudSolrClient  - Request to collection admiraltyStream failed due to (0) java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused), retry? 0
>   2017-08-02 10:02:59,688 [main] ERROR CloudSolrClient  - Request to collection admiraltyStream failed due to (0) java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused), retry? 1
>   2017-08-02 10:03:01,630 [main] ERROR CloudSolrClient  - Request to collection admiraltyStream failed due to (0) java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused), retry? 2
>   2017-08-02 10:03:02,579 [main] ERROR CloudSolrClient  - Request to collection admiraltyStream failed due to (0) java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused), retry? 3
>   2017-08-02 10:03:03,540 [main] ERROR CloudSolrClient  - Request to collection admiraltyStream failed due to (0) java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused), retry? 4
>   2017-08-02 10:03:04,484 [main] ERROR CloudSolrClient  - Request to collection admiraltyStream failed due to (0) java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused), retry? 5

Exception :

```
Exception here : No live SolrServers available to handle this request:[http://xxx.xxx.ph:8983/solr/admiraltyStream, http://xxx.xxx.ph:8983/solr/admiraltyStream, http://xxx.xxx.ph:8983/solr/admiraltyStream]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the CloudSolrClient instead of HttpSolrClient allows solrj to do a round-robin load balancing between the available solr servers, and of course is recommended in a SolrCloud context.  The "No live SolrServers” message indicates a problem with the collection admiraltyStream.

Specifically, behind the scenes, SolrJ is using LBHttpSolrClient (which is using a set of HttpSolrClient instances) for round-robin requests between shards. I think that your problem is actually this: some shard is not available (i.e. the leader and the replicas).

I would review the currently online replicas (http://solr.server:8983/#/~cloud): there you should see if all the replicas for your collection online.
There must be at least one replica per shard; and I think that in your case:

- the node you’re trying to connect directly using HttpSolrClient is up and running
- when using CloudSolrClient (i.e. Zookeeper -> Solr), there’s something wrong in your cluster state: Solr believes that there are no replicas for at least one shard, so the list of the available HttpSolrClient instances within a given instance of LBHttpSolrClient is empty